# Excel 2013 - How to remove numbers only from different positions and preceded by different symbols, letters

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, string

Is there any formula on Excel 2013 that can be used to remove digits from rows?

I want to leave only letters and symbols.

The formula needs to work for numbers that can occur at any position, although all of them are preceded by a space.

Find and replace will not work as they are different series of numbers and some of them have a comma or just a name before them.

Starting spreadsheet:

- Baleys, 23 Glencoe Road
- Carefree, Data No 4 Cabin
- Dundas Village, 222 Secret Garden
- 88 Byron Crescent, Verona

What I want:

- Baleys, Glencoe Road
- Carefree, Data No Cabin
- Dundas Village, Secret Garden
- Byron Crescent, Verona

Comment: You can nest 10 SUBSTITUTE formula replacing each digit one by one and wrap in TRIM()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I would like to suggest VBA Macro, is the fastest method and easy to use also.*

```
Function ExtractTextOnly(pWorkRng As Range) As String

Dim xValue As String
Dim OutValue As String

xValue = pWorkRng.Value

For xIndex = 1 To VBA.Len(xValue)
    If Not VBA.IsNumeric(VBA.Mid(xValue, xIndex, 1)) Then
        OutValue = OutValue & VBA.Mid(xValue, xIndex, 1)
    End If
Next
ExtractTextOnly = OutValue

End Function
```

**How it works:**

1. To open VB Editor either press **Alt+F11** or **Right Click** the Sheet TAB then hit **View Code**.
2. Click on **Insert** and select **Module.**
3. **Paste** this code into **M**odule and **Close** VB Editor.

**N.B.**

Don't forget to **S**ave the Workbook as **Macro-Enabled workbook.**

---

[image]

---

1. Formula in Cell `M52` (fill it down):

`=ExtractTextOnly(L52)`

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: Hi Rajesh, Thank you so much, that was exactly what I needed, will save me sooo much time! Have a great day! :)

Comment: @Geo_explorer,, glad to help you ,, keep asking ☺